# Pi 4 Debian buster install latest version of R - 'buster-cran40' is invalid

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, raspbian-buster, debian

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian (Debian buster). I am trying to install a recent version of R. The default R version installed with Debian buster is 3.5.2. This is way out of date and many R packages cannot run on it.

I found this article explaining how to install a more recent version of R. https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

As described, I added `deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Then, I used `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install -t buster-cran40 r-base`.

This results in `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install -t buster-cran40 r-base Reading package lists... Done E: The value 'buster-cran40' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources`

Any recommendations for installing a more recent version of R?

Comment: I have made some progress by running ```sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'```. Now when I run ```sudo apt install -t buster-cran40 r-base``` I get ```The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 4.1.2-1~bustercran.0) but 3.5.2-1 is to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 4.1.2-1~bustercran.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.```

Comment: This exact problem is discuss here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644444/how-to-install-r-4-0-on-raspbian-gnu-linux-10-buster but there is no solution.

Comment: Update your question !